# How can I do some 'checks' and if those 'checks' pass, I allow the file selection window to appear in <input type='file'>

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following:

And, I have the following:

```
$('#FolderSelect').click(function() {
    if(some condition is true)
    {
        // don't show the folder select and exit with an alert
        alert('You cant select files at the moment...');
    }
    else
    {
        //ok, proceed selecting files.. and do other things too
        $.post(.....);
    }
});
```

How can I achieve the above.. what code should I write to cancel the popping out of the file selection.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5GNCJ/1/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a `return false;` this would be the result:

```
$('#FolderSelect').click(function() {
    if(some condition is true)
    {
        // don't show the folder select and exit with an alert
        alert('You cant select files at the moment...');
        return false;      //Add this!!
    }
    else
    {
        //ok, proceed selecting files.. and do other things too
        $.post(.....);
    }
});
```

This way we 'cancel' the event default behavior, exactly what you want.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks mate, but I guess Arun got the answer first, I'd love to mark both your answers correct, but gotta go with one!

Comment: No! I answered first, check the answer times (hover 'X minutes ago' )

Comment: Actually, I answered 18 seconds before, just check. I deserve the acceptance! ;)

Comment: Ah ok, I'm sorry for that. I had seen his post first, then yours. Since I'm new to stackoverflow, do advice whether it's ok to now change the 'correct' answer to yours... or should we just leave it at this?

Comment: It's ok to change it, no problem there

Answer (score 2):

`return false` or call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of the click of file element(opening file window)

```
$('#FolderSelect').click(function(event) {
    if(some condition is true)
    {
        // don't show the folder select and exit with an alert
        alert('You cant select files at the moment...');
        event.preventDefault()
        //or return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5GNCJ/)

Comment: Oh, in your jsfiddle, you use return false, so both, event.preventDefault and return false is correct?

Comment: @omar-ali yes both are ... but in this case since want to prevent only the default action use ` event.preventDefault()` because `return false` prevents both default action and event propagation

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. Arun, Edgar says he answered before you, so I'm going to mark his answer as the correct one, if stackoverflow allows it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Arun, I hope you understand, it was a matter of seconds, and omar is very fair ;)